# PHP file form question

Tags: php, forms

**My Code :**

```
<?php
function dbAdd($first_name , $image) {

//mysql connect database code...

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET first_name = '".$first_name."', image = '".$image."'");
$mysql_close($sql);
} 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
dbAdd($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['image']);
}
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
First Name : <input type="text" name="first_name" >
Image : <input type="file" name="image"> 
<input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

The form "file" is to upload. I know that. But I wonder how to get the values so I can put the path of image in the database. The code is already working. The $first_name can already save to the database.
**Thank you for the answers.**

Jordan Pagaduan

Comment: SQL injections! Read up on PDO and prepared statements $pdo->prepare("WHERE first_name=?").
Or use input sanitization at least, $_POST->text('first_name');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file will be uploaded to a temporary place on the server when the form is submitted.

Once the form has been submitted, the `$_FILES` variable will contain all the files submitted.  In your case, you could access the uploaded file using `$_FILES['image']`.  Most likely you will want to move the file out of the temporary directory to a safer place.

For more info, have a look at [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) on the topic, specifically the page on [handling POST uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).  That second page has an example for you on how to move the uploaded file (have a look at the [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) method).

Answer (score 0):

Straight from W3C: [Upload form & $_FILE variable](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)